# How to manually create a user in Moodle?

Tags: php, authentication, moodle

I am trying to create an authentication plugin, but I am having problems when the user does not exist in the moodle database. Therefore I am trying to find a way to manually create a user.

I tried:

```
$user            = new StdClass();
$user->username  = $ucUser;
$user->auth      = 'ucauth';
$user->firstname = "First";
$user->lastname  = "Last";
$user->id        = $DB->insert_record('user', $user);
```

But it didn't work... I got an insert error. What else do I need in the `$user` object?

Comment: "I got an insert error" - what does that mean? Can you share the full and exact error message?

Answer (score 8):

User object should have the following values:

```
$user             = new StdClass();
$user->auth       = 'manual';
$user->confirmed  = 1;
$user->mnethostid = 1;
$user->email      = "email";
$user->username   = "username";
$user->password   = md5('password');
$user->lastname   = "lastname";
$user->firstname  = "firstname";
$user->id         = $DB->insert_record('user', $user);
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I recommend you to use `authenticate_user_login($username, null)` this is going to give you an empty user, wich you can complete later on in the proccess. Then you can use `complete_user_login($user);` and if you want to send the user to the edit page something like

```
if (user_not_fully_set_up($USER)) {
            $urltogo = $CFG->wwwroot.'/user/edit.php';
        }else{
            $urltogo = $CFG->wwwroot.'/';
        }

    redirect($urltogo);
```

I don't know exactly what are you trying to achieve. But I've made a plugin to connect with an external web service and it took me a while to figure out how to do it properly. I'm able to help you with anything you need.

Comment: My problem was that when I tried to manually authenticate an user (trhough a webservice), it would not work for users that were not in the moodle database (if that makes any sence). So, what I was looking for was to create the user in the moodle database so that my manual authentication could work. Something like that. But I actually found a way around, the LDAP plugin that is already in use creates this moodle user, so... when trying to use my plugin, if the user doesnt exist, I tell moodle to use the LDAP one, and next time, since the user is now created, my plugin works. Thanks 4 ur help!

Answer (score 1):

There are some values that needs to be setted when creating a user manually. I was facing the same situation and ended up with this solution:

```
global $DB;    
$user             = new StdClass();
$user->email      = strtolower('someemail'); //MOODLE requires lowercase
$user->username   = strtolower('someusername');//MOODLE requires lowercase
$user->password   = hash_internal_user_password('somepassword');
$user->lastname   = 'somelastname';
$user->firstname  = 'somename';
// These values are required. 
// Default values are stored in moodle config files but... this is easier.
$user->auth       = 'manual';
$user->confirmed  = 1;
$user->mnethostid = 1;
$user->country    = 'ES'; //Or another country
$user->lang       = 'es'; //Or another country
$user->timecreated = time();
$user->maildisplay= 0;

$user->id = $DB->insert_record('user', $user); // returns new userid
```

If you prefer, you can retrieve the whole user's data:

```
$lastid = $DB->insert_record('user', $user);
$user2 = get_complete_user_data('id', $lastid);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, include the moodle user lib file at the top of the code snippet.

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/user/lib.php');
```

Then make an object of user details in a variable $user.
example

```
$user = new stdClass();
$user->firstname = "test";
$user->lastname = "test";
$user->email = "test@xxx.com";
$user->address = "abcd";
```

And all other fields which you would like to save. Then Call this below code. It will return the user-created ID. After that, you can use that id to pull the user details or something else.

```
$user->id = user_create_user($user, false, false);
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code in an answer. Instead, add some explanation such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry, I have not enough experience to post the answer in a stack overflow. Further, I will keep it in mind. Thanks for your guidance.